# Handle NULL-values on XML-files

Tags: xml, vba, xpath, null, notepad++

I am trying to load XML-files into an Excel-spreadsheet with a MSXML2.DOMDocument object in VBA.

I have the following method:

```vb
Sub NEWTestXML()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Dim xmlNodeList As Object
    Dim getFirstChild As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.async = False: xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
    xmlDoc.Load ("H:\Anders\BankStatements\LoadXML\CAMT\20170818_070648_DANSKEBANK_DECS_20170818070531_3.xml")
    If xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error was " + xmlDoc.parseError.reason
    End If

    'Get Document Elements
    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement

    'Get first child ( same as ChildNodes(0) )
    Set getFirstChild = xmlNodeList.FirstChild
    'Print first child XML
    Debug.Print getFirstChild.XML
    'Print first child Text
    Debug.Print getFirstChild.Text

    Set getFirstChild = Nothing
    Set xmlNodeList = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

It is taken from an example found via Google.

The files I am receiving from banks contains a NULL-character which is preventing me from loading the files with the method above.

Removing the NULL-value solves the problems I am having.

They look like this:

[image: XML-file example - NULL-value]

I have been trying to load these files with Access-databases and all sorts of methods, but each time these NULL-values have gotten the better of me.

My question is:

Is there any programmatical method for removing these NULL-values, which shows in Notepad++? A parameter in MSXML2 or similar?

I have previously created a method which copies the XML-file and removes the last line, but I would like to avoid this in the current solution.

Comment: Null character is represented by "\x00". Open the file in text mode and replace all occurrences of \x00 with empty string. Then load it by XML parser.

Comment: @EylM It's not as simple as that. Properly "opening a file in text mode" requires prior knowledge of the file encoding.

Comment: It's "utf-8" - look at the sample.

Comment: Hi EyIM. Thanks for the suggestion, but as we are having hundred of files each day, opening them manually in notepad++ is not feasible. Also even though you have possibilities to edit multiple files at once, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any opportunity, fix the process that writes those faulty files.

The NULL byte is illegal in XML files, and it also doesn't occur naturally in UTF-8-encoded text files, which means that the thing that generates those files...

- ...either has no sane concept of UTF-8 or XML, or
- writes a NULL byte to the file for no good reason

Both things are bad and should be fixed in the producer, not in the consumer of those files. Go over the process that gives you those files with scrutiny and figure out where things go wrong.

---

Should that not be an option, it's still possible to load the file as plain text with a helper function, like this:

```vb
Function LoadFile(path As String, charset As String) As String
    Dim inputStream As New ADODB.Stream

    inputStream.Type = adTypeText
    inputStream.charset = charset
    inputStream.Open
    inputStream.LoadFromFile path

    LoadFile = inputStream.ReadText
End Function
```

This makes use of the fact that [`ReadText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/readtext-method) – at least for UTF-8 – stops at the first NULL byte it finds, so in your case it will read the entire file, excluding the last byte.

And then use [LoadXML()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585(v=vs.85).aspx) to parse that string into an XML document:

```vb
Sub NEWTestXML()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim docElem As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim filePath As String

    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False

    filePath = "H:\Anders\BankStatements\LoadXML\CAMT\20170818_070648_DANSKEBANK_DECS_20170818070531_3.xml"
    xmlDoc.LoadXML LoadFile(filePath, "UTF-8")

    If xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Error: " + xmlDoc.parseError.reason
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set docElem = xmlDoc.DocumentElement

    Debug.Print docElem.FirstChild.XML
    Debug.Print docElem.FirstChild.Text
End Sub
```

**There is a drawback to this method:** In order to read the string correctly, you need to know the file encoding up-front, which is exactly the thing that XML is designed to avoid.

In other words, should an XML file pop up at some point that is not UTF-8-encoded, but uses some other perfectly legal encoding, then the above approach will fail because it makes a blind assumption about the file encoding. Naturally, this is not something you would want to use long-term.

The above requires that you add two references to your VBA project

- the most recent version of the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" library
- the most recent version of the "Microsoft XML" library

Comment: Hi Tomalak

Thank you for a very elaborate, thorough and useful answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the generation of the files, which would be the correct and best way to solve the issue, as you suggest.

The NULL-character is always in the end of the file. So managed to make a method which opens the XML-file and removes everything after "</document>".

Afther this I can use the LoadXML-method.

Comment: That works, too. It still makes a blind assumption, namely that your files always end with  "</document>", but it might be good enough for yor case. One has to compromise at some point.

Comment: Beware of opening the XML file as text without specifying its encoding - that's the point I'm making above. It's easy to mess this up.